# System.AggregateException When Trying To Access Web API In Xamarin

Tags: rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have been dealing with an issue for the past day where I seem to be getting a System.AggregateException when I try to test my REST API in Xamarin.

Now, I have tried my best to narrow down the issue. Keep in mind, the issue is definitely not with the code itself, because when I go and test out the exact same code in a Console Application, it works fine and returns my data. The error is only thrown when I send the request in Xamarin.

The error is thrown on the 4th line below with the "response" variable.

(I've also tried awaiting and asynchronously running the method.)

```
public void TestReadData()
{
    string content = "error";
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/merchants").Result;
    content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

Comment: There's a few issues here, you are blocking by calling `Result`. This is also why it's wrapped in a AggregateException, you need to catch it and unwrap it to see what's going on. 
Also the reason why it's working fine in a console app is that Android uses it's own Http client implementation that is different from the default .net implementation

Comment: @JamieRees Thanks for the reply. I've surrounded it with a try/catch and have found the exception's stack trace to be the following:

Comment: 'at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x0002b] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at Biziboards.Database.DatabaseManager.TestReadData () [0x00008] in D:\\Documents\\Biziboards\\Biziboards Xamarin App\\Biziboards\\'

Comment: Not too sure where to go from here.

Comment: `at Biziboards.Database.DatabaseManager.TestReadData` this seems to be where the exception happens, you should look into this method

Comment: @DennisSchröer I'm aware, that can be seen in the method I wrote in the thread where I call 'GetAsync'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found out that aperently Xamarin's implementation of the Http namespace doesn't like locally hosted websites. I purchased an Azure subscription and uploaded my database and web application to Azure and the Xamarin app was able to retrieve the data fine.

Answer (score -1):

You need to await the call to the ReadAsync like this:

```
stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: I've tried calling it asynchronously, and also, the code breaks on the line before that due to the error.

Comment: You should also await the get Async method.
var response = await client.GetAsync("api/merchants");

Comment: I've tried this as well to no success. ' public async void TestReadData()
        {
            try
            {
                string content = "error";
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/merchants");
                content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(content);
            }'

Comment: This is a terrible answer. How is `ConfigureAwait(false)` going to fix an exception that is happening elsewhere...